# Javascript script not loading on Wordpress website

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

So I've literally copy-pasted the code from https://codepen.io/hellokatili/pen/rVvMZb (HTML in a template, CSS in styles.css and JS using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-and-footer-scripts/)

I added the JS script within   tags.

Here is the above code from codepen (after converting from HAML to HTML and SCSS to CSS).

HTML:

```
  > <div class="content">   
          <script type="text/javascript"> </script>
              <div class="slider single-item">
    >     <div class="quote-container">
    >       <div class="portrait octogon">
    >         <img src="http://www.tuacahntech.com/uploads/6/1/7/9/6179841/6166205_orig.jpg"/>
    >       </div>
    >       <div class="quote">
    >         <blockquote>
    >           <p>Meditation shabby chic master cleanse banh mi Godard. Asymmetrical Wes Anderson Intelligentsia you probably haven't heard of
    > them.</p>
    >           <cite>
    >             <span>Kristi McSweeney</span>
    >             <br/>
    >             Thundercats twee
    >             <br/>
    >             Austin selvage beard
    >           </cite>
    >         </blockquote>
    >       </div>
    >     </div>
    >     <div class="quote-container">
    >       <div class="portrait octogon">
    >         <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/51579fb2e4b0fc0d9469ff97/56cc83dfe707ebc39cf3269f/56d0b59e27d4bde4665fded3/1457365822199/"/>
    >       </div>
    >       <div class="quote">
    >         <blockquote>
    >           <p>Bespoke occupy cred seitan. Austin street art freegan Truffaut leggings aesthetic, salvia chia Brooklyn flexitarian.
    > Single-origin coffee before they sold out health goth, cornhole irony
    > keffiyeh Austin taxidermy mlkshk blog trust fund banh mi you probably
    > haven't heard of them.</p>
    >           <cite>
    >             <span>Dina Anderson</span>
    >             <br/>
    >             Blue Bottle keffiyeh
    >             <br/>
    >             Sartorial locavore Schlitz ennui
    >           </cite>
    >         </blockquote>
    >       </div>
    >     </div>   </div> </div> <svg>   <defs>
    >     <clipPath clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="octogon">
    >       <polygon points="0.50001 0.00000, 0.61887 0.06700, 0.75011 0.06721, 0.81942 0.18444, 0.93300 0.25001, 0.93441 0.38641, 1.00000 0.49999, 0.93300 0.61887, 0.93300 0.75002, 0.81556 0.81944, 0.74999 0.93302, 0.61357 0.93444, 0.50001 1.00000, 0.38118 0.93302, 0.24998 0.93302, 0.18056 0.81556, 0.06700 0.74899, 0.06559 0.61359, 0.00000 0.49999, 0.06700 0.38111, 0.06700 0.25001, 0.18440 0.18058, 0.25043 0.06700, 0.38641 0.06559, 0.50001 0.00000"></polygon>
    >     </clipPath>   </defs> </svg>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, #1abc9c, #d1f2eb);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  -webkit-animation: gradient 16s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: gradient 16s ease infinite;
  animation: gradient 16s ease infinite;
}
.content {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.slick-slider {
  margin: 30px auto 50px;
}
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.slick-prev path, .slick-next path {
  fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
.slick-prev:hover path, .slick-next:hover path {
  fill: #fff;
}
.slick-prev {
  left: -35px;
}
.slick-next {
  right: -35px;
}
.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before {
  content: none;
}
.slick-dots li button:before {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 8px;
}
.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
  color: #fff;
}
.quote-container {
  min-height: 200px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.quote-container:hover {
  cursor: grab;
}
.quote-container .portrait {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.quote-container .portrait img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.quote-container .quote {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 600;
  padding: 40px 0 40px 180px;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 1.4 !important;
  font-family: Calibri;
  color: white;
}
.quote-container .quote p {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.quote-container .quote p:first-child:before {
  content: '\201C';
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.44);
  font-size: 7.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.4em;
  left: -0.2em;
  text-shadow: none;
  z-index: -10;
}
.quote-container .quote cite {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.quote-container .quote cite span {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.dragging .quote-container {
  cursor: grabbing;
}
.octogon {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 38.11% 6.7%, 24.99% 6.72%, 18.06% 18.44%, 6.7% 25%, 6.56% 38.64%, 0% 50%, 6.7% 61.89%, 6.7% 75%, 18.44% 81.94%, 25% 93.3%, 38.64% 93.44%, 50% 100%, 61.88% 93.3%, 75% 93.3%, 81.94% 81.56%, 93.3% 74.9%, 93.44% 61.36%, 100% 50%, 93.3% 38.11%, 93.3% 25%, 81.56% 18.06%, 74.96% 6.7%, 61.36% 6.56%, 50% 0%);
  clip-path: url(#octogon);
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 5% 0%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 96% 100%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 5% 0%;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 5% 0%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 96% 100%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 5% 0%;
  }
}
@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 5% 0%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 96% 100%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 5% 0%;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
var prevButton = '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="prev"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1"><path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M 16,16.46 11.415,11.875 16,7.29 14.585,5.875 l -6,6 6,6 z" /></svg></button>',
    nextButton = '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next" aria-label="next"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M8.585 16.46l4.585-4.585-4.585-4.585 1.415-1.415 6 6-6 6z"></path></svg></button>';

$('.single-item').slick({
  infinite: true,
  dots: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 4000,
  speed: 1000,
  cssEase: 'ease-in-out',
  prevArrow: prevButton,
  nextArrow: nextButton
});

$('.quote-container').mousedown(function(){
  $('.single-item').addClass('dragging');
});
$('.quote-container').mouseup(function(){
  $('.single-item').removeClass('dragging');
});
```

The HTML and CSS part work fine but the JS isn't functioning. I'm using a different JS script on the same WP site and it works just fine. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: No see where you added `<script>` in `HTML`.

Comment: Have you added jquery? This javascript file uses jquery so you need to include the jquery library (the `$` stands for jquery)

Comment: @Jeremy Wordpress includes jQuery by itself. I would just make 2 checks: is your JS file correctly appended to DOM? Is your JS file appended `AFTER` jQuery?

Comment: @AjAX. I just edited my posts and added the <script> tag. (second line of HTML)

Comment: @Yuri I'm not quite sure what you mean, I just pasted the JS code into the plugin "Header and Footer Scripts" as mentioned. There is no separate file as such.

Comment: It wants to be `<script type="text/javascript" src="pathToFile">Or Javascript code here.</script>`.

Comment: @BobBob you code relies on jQuery, so you need it to be loaded in order to run your code. Please inspect your page source code and check whether jquery is added before your code

Comment: @AjAX. So as I said in the previous comment, the JS code in the plugin which in turn inputs it into the header and/or footer. So what pathToFile do I put. The previous script I added worked with just <script type="text/javascript"> </script>

Comment: Just paste your code `<script type="text/javascript">` here `</script>`.

Comment: @AjAX. Tried that too, didn't work!

Comment: @Yuri I have <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> before the code.

Comment: And what about `slick`? You need to check all of your dependecies. Also, be sure to run your code on `domReady`

Comment: @Yuri Understood. I wasn't aware that I would have to add all dependancies. I will verify that and let you know.

Comment: @Yuri after adding the Slick dependencies properly, it works perfectly! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the code by writing inside **jquery** ready :

```
(function($){
  'use strict';

    var prevButton = '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="prev"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1"><path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M 16,16.46 11.415,11.875 16,7.29 14.585,5.875 l -6,6 6,6 z" /></svg></button>',
        nextButton = '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next" aria-label="next"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M8.585 16.46l4.585-4.585-4.585-4.585 1.415-1.415 6 6-6 6z"></path></svg></button>';

    $('.single-item').slick({
      infinite: true,
      dots: true,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 4000,
      speed: 1000,
      cssEase: 'ease-in-out',
      prevArrow: prevButton,
      nextArrow: nextButton
    });

    $('.quote-container').mousedown(function(){
      $('.single-item').addClass('dragging');
    });
    $('.quote-container').mouseup(function(){
      $('.single-item').removeClass('dragging');
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: You also enqueue slick.css and slick.js before you enqueue this style and script.

Comment: Thank you, I added the slick dependency and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

**Can you try to add this jquery script in theme's footer.php for testing purpose like:**

var prevButton = '',
    nextButton = '';

```
jQuery('.single-item').slick({
  infinite: true,
  dots: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 4000,
  speed: 1000,
  cssEase: 'ease-in-out',
  prevArrow: prevButton,
  nextArrow: nextButton
});

jQuery('.quote-container').mousedown(function(){
  jQuery('.single-item').addClass('dragging');
});
jQuery('.quote-container').mouseup(function(){
  jQuery('.single-item').removeClass('dragging');
});
```

And also open inspect console for check any error.

Comment: Turns out I didn't add the Slick dependency and that's what the problem was!